# Intellij 14.1 Distraction free mode has a huge gap on the left side of the screen?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm really liking intellij's Distraction Free Mode. However when I try it on my machine, there is this big space on the left side of the screen. For some reason, even if I try to scroll to the left, the space is still there. It's like this huge margin on the left and it's eating a significant amount of space. How do I get rid of that? Here's a screen shot of what I have.

[image: Sample image of intelliJ's DMS on my machine]

If you look at this [blog](http://arhipov.blogspot.com/2015/03/intellij-idea-141-distraction-free-mode.html), the space on the left side of the screen is very little. I want it to look like that. How do I do that?

[image]

Edit: Ok, somehow I discovered that if I hit ctrl + mouse scroll up, the big margin on the left sort of hides itself, but in the process, the text also becomes larger, which isn't really what I was looking for at the moment. The text is just too large by that point.

Comment: kinda distracting, isn't it? :) actually your screenshot looks horrible, but if you open another source file on the right, side-by-side (the right file goes up to right border, at least on my v15 IJ), then the left margin doesn't look so bad anymore. I think the purpose of this mode is not to code in it all day, but just to go into it when you need to temporarily see more vertically

Comment: The author of the Scala plugin is Alexander Prodkhalyuzin and he's a big advocate of the distraction free mode (see his presentation at Scala Days 2016: https://youtu.be/sWikZLIOAEc?list=PLLMLOC3WM2r7kLKJPHKnyJgdiBGWaKlJf) This mode gets you closer to something like a real editor Emacs or vi experience.  Especially on smaller screens like Macbook 12", it's a good way to work on code. The issue has been reported to IDEA team: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134555 and closed.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**UPDATE:** currently, aka 27 Dec 2015, there's an [issue opened on their tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134555) regarding this feature/bug

---

The same [blog](http://arhipov.blogspot.com/2015/03/intellij-idea-141-distraction-free-mode.html) you're indicating, states the following

> **In addition, the text is center-aligned!**

This got me thinking, so I played a bit with the *right margin* features and, as you can see in the pictures below, the 2 seem related:

**1. Right margin at 80** I have it at 120 and I can't recall the default value, but this looks like yours.
[image: Right margin at 80]

**2. Right margin at 160**
[image: Right margin at 160]

In conclusion, the larger the number, the smaller the right margin, and *in addition* so to speak, the smaller the left margin.

Comment: Still looks like a work-around for a buggy behavior. Looks like distraction free mode is designed to waste the screen space instead of saving it.

Comment: @IhorKaharlichenko You may be right, but so far I found very little information regarding this mode, so I can't say for sure and I don't use this mode.

Comment: @IhorKaharlichenko If you're interested, a quick search on their bugtracker revealed [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134555)

Comment: The current root issue link (the one in the post is marked duplicate): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145837

Answer (score 23):

To get rid of the left gap in WebStorm increase the hard wrap value:

Settings > Editor > Code Style > *your language* > Wrapping and Braces > Hard Wrap at ...

Comment: tnx a lot. it helped me.

Answer (score 14):

Thank you! Works with IntelliJ 2019.1.1 as well.
CTRL+ALT+S -> code style -> increase hard wraps to > 200

[image: IntelliJ Settings]

Answer (score 5):

The issue has been updated and a better solution is suggested by Tom Gregory. The solution updates the margin used for the distraction free mode.

> For anyone coming to this bug looking for a solution, IntelliJ IDEA now offers a setting under Settings > Advanced Settings > Left margin in distraction free mode. Set it to 0 to achieve the desired result.