# No left or right margins in intellij ideas distraction free mode

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij distraction free mode, I expect that there are left and right margins and the code is position in the middle.

It used to be that way, but it somehow now does't and the code is displayed over the full screen without any margins. No matter if I am in full screen mode or not.

[image: My distraction free mode]

I'am using Intellij idea ultimate  Version: 2017.1.5.

Does anybody know how I can get back the nice centered view?

BTW: I am using Settings Repository Plugin and when I install a fresh idea instance the mode works as expected. It has to to something with my settings.

Comment: Does it help if you add `-Deditor.distraction.free.mode=true` in Help | Edit Custom VM Options?

Comment: Nope, does't help.

Comment: Try running with all the defaults after removing IDE [config/plugin folders](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519).

Comment: If you believe that it's caused by your specific settings, please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach the settings (File | Export Settings).

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't look like distraction-free mode at all. It's more like the normal view with hidden tool windows. Did you really start the distraction-free mode (via the menu for example)?

Comment: Yep, I have a shortcut for that and as I mentioned in the question, when I use a fresh idea instance, it works! It's pretty likely, that that there is something wrong with my settings. 
But I don't want to start from a fresh instance, to much of customization work went into my settings. Would be great to keep them.
Issue created https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175898

Comment: maybe you have high right margin value? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151591/intellij-14-1-distraction-free-mode-has-a-huge-gap-on-the-left-side-of-the-scree/33159047#33159047

Comment: @Kinmarui : That did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since @Peter accepted my comment as correct answer, here it is for other people to not search in comments:

IntelliJ will remove left margin when you have very high value set for right margin (it does that in attempt to center text in distraction free mode)
You can change it here [image: Right margin at 160]

See this answer for reference [Intellij 14.1 Distraction free mode has a huge gap on the left side of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151591/intellij-14-1-distraction-free-mode-has-a-huge-gap-on-the-left-side-of-the-scree/33159047#33159047)