# How to hide the left panel in WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I hide the panel with numbers but this panel remains. What is it called and how can I hide it?

I want get like this [Intellij 14.1 Distraction free mode has a huge gap on the left side of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151591/intellij-14-1-distraction-free-mode-has-a-huge-gap-on-the-left-side-of-the-scree)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Settings => Editor => General => Code Folding => Show Code Folding Outline
[image]